# To store the binary tree in an array with null values in the missing position

Tags: c++

I want to store the binary tree in the array with null values at the missing nodes.

For eg:

Input:

```
      1
     / \
    2   3
   / \   \
  4   5   6
```

Output:{1,2,3,4,5,0,6}

I have tried linear traversal of the binary tree in the array, but I want null in the missing nodes positions of the tree.

```
std::vector< int > levelorder( tree *root){
    queue<tree*> q; 
    tree* temp;
    q.push(root);
    while(!q.empty()){
        temp=q.front();
        q.pop();
        arr.push_back(temp->data);
        if(temp->left && temp->right)
        {
            q.push(temp->left);
            q.push(temp->right);
        }
        else if(temp->left && !temp->right)
        {
            q.push(temp->left);
            arr.insert(0);
        }
        else if(temp->right && !temp->left)
        {
            q.push(temp->right);
            arr.push_back(0);
        }

    }
    return arr;
}

int main() 
{ 

    tree *root = newNode(1);  
    root->left = newNode(2);  
    root->right = newNode(3);  
    root->left->left = newNode(4);  
    root->left->right = newNode(5);
    root->right->right = newNode(6);

    cout<<"Level Order traversal of binary tree is :"<<endl; 
    levelorder(root);
    for(int i =0; i<arr.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<< arr[i]<<" ";
    } 

    return 0; 
}
```

I am getting output:{1,2,3,0,4,5,6}
But I want the output as: {1,2,3,4,5,0,6}

Comment: I think you'll have to push nulls into q, and when you get a null from q add a zero to the array then. The non-null numbers on the level get added to arr when the q entry is processed, not when they are queued.

Comment: @Rup can you please edit in my code and send it back to me.

Comment: In your example, only a leaf is missing. What do you expect if a whole branch is missing?

Comment: if in my example 6 is also missing then I want output as:{1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: I don't care about missing, I care about only missing node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Algorithm

The following code supports missing sub-trees and stop as soon as no meaningful nodes are present:

```
std::vector<int> levelorder(tree *root){
    int null_in_queue = 0;
    std::queue<tree*> q;
    std::vector<int> arr;
    q.push(root);
    while(q.size() != null_in_queue){
        tree* temp=q.front();
        q.pop();
        if(!temp)
        {
           arr.push_back(0);
           q.push(nullptr);
           q.push(nullptr);
           null_in_queue++; // One was removed, two were added
        }
        else
        {
            arr.push_back(temp->data);
            q.push(temp->left);
            q.push(temp->right);
            if (!temp->left) null_in_queue++;
            if (!temp->right) null_in_queue++;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

It pushes virtual nodes (nullptr) in the queue and count the number of virtual nodes. When only virtual nodes are remaining, it terminates.

#### Complexity

The time and memory complexity of this algorithm is `O(n)`, where `n` is the size of the output array. The size of this array is at most the node count (minus one) of a full tree up to the deepest node. For a tree of depth `d`, the algorithm has complexity `O(2^d)`.

Details: The code in the loop is constant (amortized) and the `q` vector contains nodes and virtual nodes, which contains at most 2^(d+1) nodes (an additional row of virtual nodes will be added before the algorithm finishes). This means that the whole algorithm will execute in `O(2^(d+1)) ~ O(2*2^d) ~ O(2^d)`.

Comment: An error is coming while pushing the nullptr,Error is: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Your compiler may not support the `nullptr` keyword (it appeared in C++11). Replace `nullptr` with `0`.

Comment: what will be the time complexity for this function

Comment: @UtkarshGoyal I added a paragraph describing the complexity of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the empty nodes are properly initialized to `nullptr`:

```
while(!q.empty()){
    tree* temp=q.front();
    q.pop();
    if(!temp)
       arr.push_back(0);
    else if (temp->left || temp->right)//Only recurse into internal nodes, not leafs
    {
        arr.push_back(temp->data);
        q.push(temp->left);
        q.push(temp->right);
    }
}
```

I would like to note that this won't print missing subtrees, only missing leafs. Please specify if it should.

Comment: the output is {1,2,3,4,5,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0} why these extra zeros are coming in the end

Comment: Because those nodes in the lowest level are also missing leafs, both of them. This is not probably what you wanted, sorry ,will edit the code shortly.